# Using amChart in qooxdoo mobile

Tags: qooxdoo, amcharts

I'm trying to use amChart in a qooxdoo mobile application. The problem I'm facing right now is that in qooxdoo I don't have a `<div>` tag to draw the chart at. Because `chart.write("chartdiv");` expects a `<div>` container. In qooxdoo desktop it would work like this:

`chart.write(widget.getChildControl("body").getContentElement().getDomElement());`

Unfortunatly the qooxdoo Mobile widget does not provide any of these methodes.

Can somebody tell me how this can be done with a qooxdoo Mobile widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qx.Mobile is much nearer to the DOM tree than qx.Desktop.

A default widget is based on a "div" tag. So if you use, for example, a qx.ui.mobile.container.Composite(), and then call getContentElement(), you will have the required "div" element.

Another way could be the http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.mobile.embed.Html